# ORA-01001 after second running code attempt

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have code like this

DBConnection.EnsureConnectionToDB()

```
    private static OracleConnection con;
    public static OracleConnection EnsureConnectionToDB()
    {
        if (con == null)
            con = new OracleConnection();

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "xxx";

            con.Open();
        }
        return con;
    }
```

GetData()

```
    public static void GetData()
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("procedure", DBConnection.EnsureConnectionToDB());

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_inv", OracleDbType.Decimal, 1, ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //here on second time I get ORA-01001

        //some data maniupulation

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

Before get data I run 2-3 another command.

On first run of the GetData() all work smoothly, but when I run it again I get ORA-01001.

We have open cursor set on 600. I asked db_admin to enlarge it to 3000. But I don't think it will help...

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I stuck up on some clue.

In pl/sql I got this:

```
procedure procedure(
       i_inv    IN NUMBER
     , p_cursor OUT sys_refcursor
)
as
    vSQL           varchar2(32000) := '';
    v_dyn_cursor   INTEGER;
    v_dummy        PLS_INTEGER;
begin
    vSQL := 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL';

    v_dyn_cursor := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;

    DBMS_SQL.parse
    (
          v_dyn_cursor
        , vSQL
        , DBMS_SQL.native
    );

    v_dummy := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE (v_dyn_cursor);
    p_cursor := DBMS_SQL.to_refcursor (v_dyn_cursor);
end;
```

It could be problem with DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR. What do you think about it?

Comment: Your code suggests that you are reusing or caching `OracleConnection`, which is almost certainly not what you want to do. Restrict the scope as much as possible, wrap things in `using`, and let connection pooling take care of caching. Otherwise, you have to do things like recreate the connection whenever an error renders it unusable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you tell more what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is related to `open_cursors` parameter's value to be high enough.

It seems in the code body, there is a step where you close your cursor, and then you try to call that already closed one.

Comment: No, I'm quite sure, that I don't close it.